# Picking a picture either from photos or multimedia, but not by recent images

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I would like to pick picture similar to whatsapp:

### Code:

```
   public void pickImage()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19)
        {
            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_SELECT_PICTURE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
        if (null == data) return;
        Uri originalUri = null;
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            originalUri = data.getData();
        }
        else if (requestCode == KITKAT_SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            originalUri = data.getData();
            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            // Check for the freshest data.
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri, takeFlags);
        }
    }
```

### Question:

The above can pick pictures and then showing pic properly in an imageview. However, during the picking process, it messes up the pictures photoed by camera (called album) and pictures in other media, and is sorted by most recent images.

How could i make it similar to whatsapp, picking image from a folder containing only but all images taken from camera, or a folder containing all other multimedia, INSTEAD OF messing up camera photos and mutimedia pictures by most recently added?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to get recent path properly mostly it gives null..

Comment: I mean not to show the picking page in order of decending date, I would like it to be similar to whatsapp, in either by images from camera, or other images from mutimedia apart from camera?

Answer (score 0):

Use [MediaStore.Images.Media.query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#query(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function with order by set DSC [DATE_ADDED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATE_ADDED) field. You can set content URI for internal/external storage based on your requirement.

Comment: i would like to separate the camera pictures from other multimedia pictures, instead of messing the camera photos and mulimedia images altogether sorting in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope so it will be helpful my problem was fix out with help of this code..

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
```

and:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this will separate the camera pictures from other multimedia pictures?